# How is this code working?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I am working with the company code and I see this:

```
ClassName(/* bunch of parameters */)
  .someFunc(/* bunch of parameters */)
  .someFunc(/* bunch of parameters */)
  .someFunc(/* bunch of parameters */)
  ;
```

Now I have never seen this and didn't know something like this could work (the code compiles in the company solution) so I tried it out but I had no such luck. The code failed to compile due to incorrect syntax. I am baffled as to how it is working on the company's solution...? Maybe I am overlooking something?

Comment: maybe you're missing some library?

Comment: This is called function chaining - but as @John said, you're probably missing some headers somewhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This technique is called [Method Chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining). It basically works by returning a reference to `*this` in every method that you call. This allows you to directly call another method on the returned object (called chaining).

Comment: Just being pedantic: (but some beginners may use your answer explicitly): But reference to '*this'

Comment: In C# this is quite popular with a number of libraries and called 'Fluent' style.

Answer (score 4):

Huh? What's strange about this? Doesn't this just mean that `someFunc()` is declared like so:

```
ClassName& someFunc(/*arguments*/)
{
  /*do stuff*/
  return *this;
}
```

in order to support chaining? Just like the stream operators?

Comment: doh! I forgot about this... learned it quite some time ago regarding stream operators but since I never used it or saw it being used in any other code, I never connected the two.

Comment: I'm sure it's quite strange if you've never seen method chaining before.

Comment: It's strange anyway, becaus emethod chaining is an abomination. </rant>

Answer (score 1):

`someObj.someFunc()` may return a reference to `someObj`, like this:

```
class ClassName {
    ClassName &someFunc() {
        return *this; // return current object, nothing created
    }
};

ClassName someObj;

someObj.someFunc().someFunc(); // chain function calls on same object
ClassName().someFunc().someFunc(); // same, but now object is a temporary
```

This also works with a direct object return type, as opposed to a reference. In this pattern, the object may be modified at each step.

```
class ClassName {
    ClassName increment() const {
        return *this + 1; // return a newly created object
    }
};

ClassName someObj;
someObj.increment().increment(); // does not modify someObj, returns temporary
```

The key to understanding such code always lies in looking at the declaration of the function of interest.